# Gradient notation - understanding subscripts

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, partial-derivative

In one of my textbooks the following notation is used to describe strain components in a displacement field:

---

$$\begin{bmatrix} S_1 \\ S_2 \\ S_3 \\ S_4 \\ S_5 \\ S_6 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial z} \\ \frac{\partial u_y}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial u_x}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial u_x}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial u_y}{\partial x} \end{bmatrix}$$

or

$$S_I = \nabla_{Ij}u_j$$

---

I am a little bit confused as to how exactly I should interpret the subscripts in the expression $S_I = \nabla_{Ij}u_j$.  Take for instance $S_4$.  We are supposed to have:

$$S_4 = \nabla_{4j}u_j = \frac{\partial u_y}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial y}$$

But I can't see how logically the subscripts indicate this.  If anyone can explain this to me, I would really be grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought it made non sense as well.

But after looking it up it seems that in this context, $\nabla$ is a symbol that stands for

$$ \nabla = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial x} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} & 0 & \frac{\partial}{\partial x}
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Don't ask me why, I find it very weird and I am a total stranger to mechanics :)

Comment: Where did you find this? Could you post a link please?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, if you could provide a link to this, then I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Well, I saw it in there: http://www.rpi.edu/~des/3DElasticity.ppt

Comment: Great.  Thanks a lot!